# How to import a crate as a sub module?

Tags: module, rust, rust-crates

I'd like to import a crate into my library, and then use that crate as if it's a module in my library. If I do this:

```
extern crate sdl2;
pub use sdl2;
```

That gives me an error, suggesting I use `sdl2::*`, but I don't want to drag all the names from the crate into my library, I want them addressed as a sub-module, for example:

```
my_library::sdl2::init()
```

I also tried this:

```
pub extern crate sdl2;
```

That compiles, but I have no idea what it does. It doesn't seem to make the crate publicly accessible from my library though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use renaming in `use` and `extern crate`:

```
extern crate sdl2 as sdl2_;
pub use sdl2_ as sdl2;
```

I personally found how to do it in [`stdx`](https://github.com/brson/stdx) crate (which appears to be deprecated/abandoned, though, at least for now).

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

```
extern crate sdl2;
mod sdl2 {
    pub use ::sdl2::*;
}
```

Should work -- untested though.